# Vgs(on) and Vgs(off) for a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I am looking to design a common-source amplifier and I have found a research paper that uses the 2N7000, in designing one. The paper can be found [here.](https://peer.asee.org/a-practical-approach-to-designing-mosfet-amplifiers-for-a-specific-gain.pdf)

However, I am confused, as there is mention of "Vgs(off)" and "Vgs(on)" that is stated as 2V and 10V respectively, for an "Ids(on)" of 1A, for the mosfet (datasheet can be found [here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/70226/70226.pdf)). Where do these values come from and how can I look at any MOSFET datasheet and read off these values, if possible? From my little understanding of biasing a MOSFET, I am aware of "Vgs", but not an "on" or "off" relation.

Any help in understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Any voltage smaller than Vgs(th) (lower than 2V) is Vgs(off) and any Vgs large then Vgs(th) is Vgs(on).

Comment: The term Vgs(off) doesn't appear anywhere in the linked data sheet.

Comment: It seems like the author assumes that Vgs(off) = Vgs(th) = Vgs threshold voltage.  The MOSFET will start conducting current if Vgs is larger than 2V.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this @G36.

Comment: @G36 Only if you ignore the subthreshold current, and define "on" as "conducting a very tiny current". Your statement is an enormous simplification of real behavior, and could be misleading to inexperienced readers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee the 2N7000 will be mostly off at Vgs=2.0V. As you can see from the datasheet, it could conduct as much as 1mA at Vgs=Vds= 0.8V at 25°C (worse at higher temperatures, as Vgs(th) has a negative temperature coefficient. At 2.0 V the **typical** Id is 0.25mA which I don't think many would consider "off", even typically. If you want to make sure it turns off for sure, over temperature, 400mV might be a better choice than 2V.

With Vgs = 10V the 'on' resistance is well specified in the datasheet, as it is at Vgs = 5V. The on resistance has a positive temperature coefficient, so that should be considered, especially when using it as a switch.

The equation that the thermistor guy used indicates he is using Vgs(off) to mean Vgs(th), and is assuming the saturation region. From the paper:

[image]

Which is the simplified transfer function for a MOSFET in the saturation region. And then he uses the Vgs(on) to calculate K. Note that the equation yields Id = 0 for Vgs = Vgs(th), so it won't be an accurate transfer function when Vgs is close to Vgs(th).